# How do I extract data from a Yahoo Finance JSON using node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, yahoo-api

I built out a simple request function to get a JSON from the Yahoo Finance API but am having trouble extracting data from the JSON.

Here's my function

```
var request = require("request");

var stock_url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/FB/quote?format=json&view=%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bdetail";

request(stock_url, function (error, response, body) { 
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {  
        var stock_data = body;
        console.log("Yahoo Finance API: ", stock_data)
        var stock_price = stock_data.list.resources[0].resource.fields.price;
        console.log("stock_price: ", stock_price);       
    };
});
```

The JSON returned is stored in `var stock_data` successfully and I then try to extract the "price" data with `var stock_price = stock_data.list.resources[0].resource.fields.price` but am getting a TypeError: cannot read property 'resources' of undefined.

Below is the JSON, I've tried multiple derivatives for `var stock_price` with no luck. Any help is much appreciated.

```
{
  "list": {
    "meta": {
      "type": "resource-list",
      "start": 0,
      "count": 1
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "resource": {
          "classname": "Quote",
          "fields": {
            "name" : "Facebook, Inc.",
            "price" : "116.620003",
            "symbol" : "FB",
            "ts" : "1465588800",
            "type" : "equity",
            "utctime" : "2016-06-10T20:00:00+0000",
            "volume" : "18510826"              
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Need to parse it to an object first from string

Comment: when you do the next code `console.log(typeof body)` what is printed?

Comment: @DanielKrom string is printed. Parsing it to an object worked. Thanks charlietfl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Request**](https://github.com/request/request) returns `body` as string value.

You should then parse it with `var stock_data = JSON.parse(body)`.

BTW you can use existing [yahoo-finance](https://github.com/pilwon/node-yahoo-finance) implementations for node and avoid to rewrite it you own.

Comment: Worked, thanks for the help and pointing out yahoo-finance implementations.